# How to create a pre-scaled font for a CPCL printer

Tags: printing, fonts, zebra-printers

I've got a .NET Compact Framework application that uses a Zebra QL220+ printer.  I drive the printer via CPCL printer language, and I now need to print some output that cannot be achieved with just the resident fonts.  I'd like to create some pre-scaled fonts (which are then downloaded as .cpf files to the printer) but for the life of me I cannot find how to do this.  I have the Label Vista tool from Zebra, and despite the fact that the Help file states this can be done, my "Fonts" menu is disabled.  Does anyone know a way to create the CPF files?

Comment: what version of LabelVista are you running?

Comment: Version 3.5.2 according to the Help-About.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I don't know why it's grayed out in `v3.5.2`, `3.5.1` works, but I couldn't find a download link for it.

Try this though.

1. Click on Tools->Text and then click in the label somewhere to enter a
2. Under "Type of Font" select TTF if you want to convert a TTF
3. Click Select Font
4. Pick your font and click OK
5. Now "Make Font" should now be enabled, click it
6. Now you can save the font as a cpf file

hope that helps!

Comment: Hot diggity!  An odd place to tuck that functionality but it worked!

Comment: Not one of the intuitive functions... How do you use this pre-scaled font on the device? I've uploaded it to the printer and I know it's SETLP command, but the font just doesn't change. I tried with and without .cpf extension :(