# Zebra MZ220 (CPCL) tahoma font

Tags: zebra-printers

I'm porting an app to android from windows mobile. This app has printing support. 
In Windows mobile I used PrinterCe framework, but in the android app I have written a framework to create CPCL labels. 
Everything works ok except for the font. In the windows mobile app I can set the font doing:

```
((PrinterCE)m_Printer).FontName = "Tahoma";
```

but as CPCL manual says I can choose between 7 fonts but tahoma is not in the list.
What method PrinterCE uses to allow me printing using Tahoma??
I think the framework takes care of upload the font to the printer.. but how do I use that font once uploaded??

**Update:**
I'm using the printer in Line Printing Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used PrinterCE, but I assume it writes text, images, barcodes, etc onto a canvas and then at the end of the document, sends it down to the printer as an image, which is why it would let you use any font available on the CE device. If you want to use a non-native font on a CPCL printer, you have to first download it to the printer. ([See this answer here on how to make pre-scaled fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401354/how-to-create-a-pre-scaled-font-for-a-cpcl-printer/9742132#9742132)).  Then you would have to use that font in your format.